# Monthly average for a given location in a daily netcdf file

Tags: netcdf

I have a netcdf file with the daily precipitation (for a whole decade) in every latitude and longitude, it's in the form (lon,lat,time). I want to get the monthly average for the longitude=-118.25:-84.75 and for the latitude=13.25:33.25. I need to write another netcdf file in which the variable is monthly precipitation given by (lon,lat,time) but i dont know how to extract the ranges and how to obtain the monthly average since the months are repeated each year.

Comment: which language?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the tool called `cdo` and operator `sellonlatbox`:

```
cdo -sellonlatbox -118.25,-84.75,13.25,33.25 filein fileout
```

filein is the name of your input file and fileout is the name of the output.

Afterwards you can use operator `monmean` to calculate monthly means:

```
cdo -monmean fileout final_file
```

Comment: I cannot use any other tools or packages other than ncdf4

Comment: can you share some small subset of data/file? In any case, working only with Python and netCDF4 over a large set of data, will be slow. It is easy to write the Python code, but the tool I mentioned is much-much faster and relatively easy to use from command line.

Comment: i have the daily pr for the given lon and lat, but i have time values from 1-3652 and i wanna transform them from daily to monthly 
nc<-nc_open("pr-ssp370")
lon<-ncvar_get(nc,"lon")
lat<-ncvar_get(nc, "lat")
time<-ncvar_get(nc, "time")
data<-ncvar_get(nc,"pr") 
LonSt <- which( nc$dim$lon$vals == -118.25) 
LonEn <- which( nc$dim$lon$vals == -84.75) 
LatSt <- which( nc$dim$lat$vals == 33.25)
LatEn <- which( nc$dim$lat$vals == 13.25)
countLon <- LonEn-LonSt+1
countLat <- LatEn-LatSt+1
prcut<- ncvar_get( nc, "pr", start=c(LonSt,LatSt,1), count=c(countLon,countLat,-1))